# QnAMaker Patch - Update Knowledgebase Error 431

Tags: power-automate, azure-qna-maker

I am pushing a patch request from Power Automate. The flow was to map the SharePoint folders and generate a multi-turn conversation based on the folder hierarchies.

The request has 4 level deep context and around 100 lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. This was a simple mistake.
I added the body to the cookie field.